# In Delphi IDE, how to quickly determine the location of an open non-project-related file?

Tags: delphi, ide

This is probably a question that has an easy/simple/obvious answer, but I've found myself asking it many, many times, and never able to answer it:

When I Ctrl-click a class name, Delphi loads up the unit that defines it (assuming it's on the browse path).  Once it's open in the IDE, is there a way to quickly find out where that PAS file resides folder-wise, on the hard drive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Delphi 2009 you can hover over the tab at the top of the code.

Comment: I *knew* it was something simple, but didn't have a clue where it was.  Works like this is D2007 too.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 32):

Erika's got a good answer.  Here's an even better one:  You can have Delphi open the Windows folder and highlight the file for you.  Here's how to set it up:

Tools menu -> Configure Tools -> Add

```
Title: Explore
Program: Explorer.exe
Working dir: <leave blank>
Parameters: /select, $EDNAME
```

This is a simple little trick that can be very handy if you want to locate a file.

EDIT:  One note: If you currently have a Windows Explorer window open to the folder that the file's in, in XP it will activate the window but *not* select the file. In Vista and Win7, it will open a new copy of the window.

Comment: Mason, you rock.  This is one of those moments I wish I could check TWO answers as the answer!  Thanks so much -- this is great.

Comment: Sweet. I've used this before but that /select parameter rocks... Up vote!

Comment: This should be as default in Delphi. +1

Comment: ...and, unlike the tab hover, this works with Delphi 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you install [CNPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en), a free Delphi plugin, you can also right click on a tab and will be offered a popup menu which includes the ability to open the edited file in explorer (much like Mason's tools trick).

Answer (score 3):

Usually File->Save As also defaults to the correct folder.

For example, if you position the caret inside a unit name and press Ctrl-Enter (which, BTW, works even if program is running in the debugger when Ctrl-Click doesn't) and do File->Save As, you'll be taken to the correct folder.

At least that's how I was always doing that - before learning two new tricks here :)